# User creation issue in API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on API.

I am having three files to load on irb for creation of new user in API . I am able to load two files but third file not able to load. that's why not able to test the methods.

i am getting error like

```
irb(main):002:0> require_relative 'user.rb'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> require_relative 'account.rb'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> require_relative 'client.rb'
=> false
irb(main):005:0> test = Account.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Account
        from (irb):5
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Maybe your `Account` class is namespaced? Show your `account.rb` file.

Comment: require_relative './client.rb'
require_relative './user.rb'

module B
 # Account class defines properties of the end-user's CloudFS paid account
 class Account < User

Comment: can you please posts those files here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Account` class is namespaced with `B` module, so you should:

```
test = B::Account.new
```

You could read more about namespacing in Ruby here:
http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/35-modules/lessons/80-modules-as-namespaces

Comment: Thanks But at a time we can load more than two files on irb ryt.

Comment: @user4443990 I don't understand. Explain a little bit more.

Comment: I want to load 3 files on irb then only i am able to create new user. I am getting error while loading third file... is it specific  irb having some limitation for loading file.@Marek

Comment: No, you must have messed something up. But I can't say anything 'til you show me this error message.

Comment: Hi Got it...It matters sequence while loading files on irb :)